# How to make the latest entry element in a listview visible all the time

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a chat application in which I am using list view to display each chat message.I made the xml layout in a such a way that top a list down to it an edit text and a button.
My problem is that when the chat message exceeds the screen size it goes below the edit text so that i have to scroll upword to see the message.. I want all the previous message go upper while the latest message should be visible shown just above the edittext view..
Can any body help me to solve this problem ..
My xml layout code is shown below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
     >

  <ListView 
  android:id="@+id/listView"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1.0"
  ></ListView>


<LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/llout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"

       android:gravity="bottom">
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_inputText"
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "Text here"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
       />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Send"
        />
</LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

java code :

```
public class AndyChatActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    public ListView msgView;
    List<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
    LazyAd l;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> msgList;
//  public ArrayAdapter<String> msgList=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listtest);

         msgView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        msgList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        msgView.setAdapter(msgList);

//      msgView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgList.getCount() - 1);

        Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_S);

        receiveMsg();
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(AndyChatActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                final EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_i);
                String msg=txtEdit.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(AndyChatActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //msgList.add(txtEdit.getText().toString());
                Log.d("checking", "below botton");
                sendMessageToServer(txtEdit.getText().toString());
                msgView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgList.getCount() - 1);

            }           
        });

        //receiveMsg();
        //----------------------------
        //server msg receieve
        //-----------------------



        //End Receive msg from server//
    }
    public void sendMessageToServer(String str) {

        final String str1=str;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //String host = "https://www.tudens.in";
                String host="192.168.1.4";
                //Toast.makeText(AndyChatActivity.this, "thread Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //String host2 = "127.0.0.1";
                PrintWriter out;
                try {

                    Socket socket = new Socket(host, 8008);
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    Log.d("1", "good");

                    // out.println("hello");
                    out.println(str1);
                    Log.d("2", "gd");
                    out.flush();
                    String str="Me : "+str1;
                    displayMsg(str);

                    Log.d("", "hello");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("", "hello222");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("", "hello4333");
                }

            }
        }).start();
            }



    public void receiveMsg()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("checking", "inside tread");

                final  String host="192.168.1.4";
                //final String host="10.0.2.2";
                //final String host="localhost";
                Socket socket = null ;
                BufferedReader in = null;
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(host,8008);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                while(true)
                {
                    String msg = null;
                    try {
                        msg = in.readLine();
                        Log.d("","MSGGG:  "+ msg);

                        //msgList.add(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(msg == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        displayMsg(msg);
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();


    }

    public void displayMsg(String msg)
    { 
        final String mssg=msg;
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                values.add(mssg);
                l=new LazyAd(AndyChatActivity.this,values);
            //  msgList.add(mssg);
                msgView.setAdapter(l);
                msgView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgList.getCount() - 1);
                Log.d("","hi");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`RelativeLayout`** as the **root layout**.

Put the EditText at the bottom of the RelativeLayout using **`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`**.

Place the ListView on top of the Layout containing the EditText using **`android:layout_above="@+id/llout"`**

That way your List will scroll on top of the EditText automatically, when the entries exceed the screen size.

This is how things should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llout"></ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_inputText"
            android:layout_width="125px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text here"
            android:layout_weight="0.8" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried, but not getting showing some error,may as i am fresher in android didn't get it. can you please edit my above xml code for proper working thank You

Comment: Just copy and paste my code. I tried it out. Should be working perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by forcefully closing window ? First check if it is being shown properly in the Graphical Window or not.

Comment: Try adding `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to the ListView, but that actually shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: a window appearing in emulator which shows application has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: Then my friend, there is probably nothing wrong in the XML. Check your Java code. Yur application is crashing due to your Java code. Check the LogCat and tell me the error that is being shown there. **Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat**. The reason behind the crashing would be given there.

Comment: 09-14 17:43:04.796: E/AndroidRuntime(647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 17:43:04.796: E/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.UTEP.android/edu.UTEP.android.AndyChatActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
09-14 17:43:04.796: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-14 17:43:04.796: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

Comment: You are trying to convert your RelativeLayout into a LinearLayout. That is why the class cast exception. Remember that you changed the root layout to a RelativeLayout in the XML code. Looks like you forgot to change that in Java.

Comment: The ids of the EditText don't match. You should be using `final EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_inputText);`

Comment: no final EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_i);

Comment: Uhh.. the android:id of your EditText is txt_inputText.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`android:transcriptMode` on your `ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3atranscriptMode), setting it to `normal` or `alwaysScroll`.

Comment: No still the same problem exists